# Replacing Text in Generated Table Header - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I have a generated table that looks like this:

```
<table width="100%" id="BdwpRows" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
<tbody>
<tr class="BDLheader-style" valign="top">
<th width="1" class="ms-vh"></th>

<th align="left" class="ms-vh"><table class="ms-unselectedtitle" id="msomenuid7" onmouseover="OnMouseOverAdHocFilter(this, 'Header1 @Header1 text;1033 ctl00$ctl45$g_ca983ec5_e788_482a_9f71_12f0dad6f125')" cellspacing="0" ctxnum="1"><tbody><tr><td width="100%" class="ms-vb" nowrap="">Header Text 1</td>
<td style="right: 1px;"><img width="13" style="visibility: hidden;" alt="Open Menu" src="/_layouts/15/images/menudark.gif?rev=41"></td></tr></tbody></table></th>

<th align="left" class="ms-vh"><table class="ms-unselectedtitle" id="msomenuid2" onmouseover="OnMouseOverAdHocFilter(this, 'Original_Budget_Amount @Original_Budget_Amount text;1033 ctl00$ctl45$g_ca983ec5_e788_482a_9f71_12f0dad6f125')" cellspacing="0" ctxnum="1"><tbody><tr><td width="100%" class="ms-vb" nowrap="">Budget Amount</td>
<td style="right: 1px;"><img width="13" style="visibility: hidden;" alt="Open Menu" src="/_layouts/15/images/menudark.gif?rev=41"></td></tr></tbody></table></th>

<th align="left" class="ms-vh"><table class="ms-unselectedtitle" onmouseover="OnMouseOverAdHocFilter(this, 'Header3 @Header3 number;1033 ctl00$ctl45$g_ca983ec5_e788_482a_9f71_12f0dad6f125')" cellspacing="0" ctxnum="1"><tbody><tr><td width="100%" class="ms-vb" nowrap="">Header Text 3</td>
<td style="right: 1px;"><img width="13" style="visibility: hidden;" alt="Open Menu" src="/_layouts/15/images/menudark.gif?rev=41"></td></tr></tbody></table></th>

<th align="left" class="ms-vh"><table class="ms-unselectedtitle" onmouseover="OnMouseOverAdHocFilter(this, 'Header4 @Header4 number;1033 ctl00$ctl45$g_ca983ec5_e788_482a_9f71_12f0dad6f125')" cellspacing="0" ctxnum="1"><tbody><tr><td width="100%" class="ms-vb" nowrap="">Header Text 4</td>
<td style="right: 1px;"><img width="13" style="visibility: hidden;" alt="Open Menu" src="/_layouts/15/images/menudark.gif?rev=41"></td></tr></tbody></table></th>

<th align="left" class="ms-vh"><table class="ms-unselectedtitle" onmouseover="OnMouseOverAdHocFilter(this, 'Header5 @Header5 text;1033 ctl00$ctl45$g_ca983ec5_e788_482a_9f71_12f0dad6f125')" cellspacing="0" ctxnum="1"><tbody><tr><td width="100%" class="ms-vb" nowrap="">Header Text 5</td>
<td style="right: 1px;"><img width="13" style="visibility: hidden;" alt="Open Menu" src="/_layouts/15/images/menudark.gif?rev=41"></td></tr></tbody></table></th>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I am needing to change the text 'Budget Amount' using JavaScript. I am having trouble figuring out how to select this as there is no defined id element.

Comment: Do you own that html? If you do just add it. If you don't, do you have jquery available?

Comment: This is coming from a SharePoint generated HTML. The markup is the general framework that I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

The markup is kinda screwed up, bit looks like you need to do the following with:

```js
var tgt = document.querySelector('table.ms-unselectedtitle > tbody >  tr > td');
tgt.innerHTML = "Whatever U want";
```

```css
table {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
td,
th {
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table id="BdwpRows">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="BDLheader-style">
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <!--This is another table?-->

      <table class="ms-unselectedtitle">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Budget Amount</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using jQuery, you can actually clean this up up into a single line of code. What this does is finds the table using your `ms-unselectedtitle` class, then finds the `td` (skipping searching for the tr), and then sets the value of the text. Also, make sure when you present demo code, that you include all of the wrappers as well. I had to close out the the outside table row, body, and actual table.

```js
$('.ms-unselectedtitle').find('td').html('New Text Value');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="BdwpRows">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="BDLheader-style">
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>
        <table class="ms-unselectedtitle">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Budget Amount</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: My first reaction was to use jQuery, but the OP has JavaScript as tags and didn't specifically request jQuery (AFAIK)

Comment: @zer00ne Right, but the catch is in a case like this if he's going to start using a lot of DOM driven elements, he may want to start. Javascript is pretty powerful on it's own, and there certainly are cases where you don't need or even shouldn't use jQuery. This is an instance where if he continues to expand his code, it might be worthwhile. This way he has both routes, and can learn from both hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the outer table using the id and then drill into the inner table using querySelector and querySelectorAll methods. For example...

```
var td = document.getElementById("BdwpRows").querySelector("tbody").querySelector("tr").querySelectorAll("th")[2].querySelector("table").querySelector("tbody").querySelector("tr").querySelector("td");
td.textContent = "new text here";
```

If you know that the "ms-unselectedtitle" class is only used in one place then you could shortern the process by finding the inner table directly and then drilling down from there like in some of the other answers.

Comment: This one gives an Unable to get property 'querySelector' of undefined or null reference

Comment: I tested the code in both IE11 and Chrome using the HTML table listed in the question. It worked fine for me. Are you using a different browser? Are you used the same table listed in the question? My code is assuming that identical structure. Note that I did fix the supplied HTML by closing all the open tags for the outer table.

Comment: Bobby, I'm using IE11. The table is generated by SharePoint so I don't have access to edit the HTML directly. I'm going to update the framework code above with the actual code. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try using `document.querySelectorAll()` , `for` loop , `.children` , `.item()` , `.textContent`

```
var tr = document.querySelectorAll("#BdwpRows tr");
var text = "Budget Amount";
var replacement = "New Budget Amount";
for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
  if (tr[i].children.item("td").textContent === text) {
    tr[i].children.item("td").textContent = replacement
  };
}
```

```js
var tr = document.querySelectorAll("#BdwpRows tr");
var text = "Budget Amount";
var replacement = "New Budget Amount";
for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
  if (tr[i].children.item("td").textContent === text) {
    tr[i].children.item("td").textContent = replacement
  };
}
```

```html
<table id="BdwpRows">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="BDLheader-style">
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>
        <table class="ms-unselectedtitle">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Budget Amount</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't give any console errors but I also doesn't change the text in the header.

Comment: @Jim _"This doesn't give any console errors but I also doesn't change the text in the header."_ Can include full `html` at Question ? , create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: When I go to the jsfiddle, it still shows Budget Amount as the header text and not New Budget Amount. I'm in IE11.

Comment: @Jim Displaying "New Budget Amount" here . Try substituting `.innerHTML` for `.textContent` http://jsfiddle.net/g21oayu6/1/

Comment: It works in Chrome but not IE 11 (IE 11 with default settings). Strange.

Comment: @Jim ie does not support `children` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children . Try using `Array.prototype.forEach` http://jsfiddle.net/g21oayu6/4/

Comment: How would this change if the text "Budget Amount" was wrapped in an <a> tag?

Comment: There must be something in the SharePoint code that isn't letting this execute like it should. I have the js file loaded after the page, everything runs, there are no diagnostic errors. Just nothing changes.